# Can a node in a linked list have a dynamic array?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Can I have this kind of a structure in a linked list?

```
public class myLinkedList{
myLinkedList parent;
String data;
myLinkedList[] next;
}
```

The problem is, this node might or might not have multiple connections.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can. The `next` array can have multiple values, including none. Is the question just that?

Comment: Yes. I know that nodes of a Linked List get stored in the heap. But I wasn't sure if an already created node could have more memory locations allocated.

Comment: You can "remake" the array at any time just by assigning a new one: `next = new myLinkedList[99]; next = new myLinkedList[1]; next = new myLinkedList[30];`. Keep in mind we are assigning a brand new array here everytime, not expanding its size. If you need dynamic size, you should go for a Collection like `ArrayList`.

Comment: that way It can be either a tree, a topology, or a FSM

Answer (score 3):

The language allows your class to hold your reference `next` to the `mylinkedlist` array.

However, a linked list is linear. Your structure may be a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29) or a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29).

Comment: Thank you. I understood what I am doing here. I have been studying a lot of Linked List and I keep thinking in those terms. You are right. This is a graph problem that I am working on.

Answer (score 1):

Singley-linked lists, by definition, have one connection (pointer to the next node). Doubley-linked lists have two (one pointing to previous node, the other pointing to the next node). If you are going to have multiple connections, you should use a tree, or a graph.